# Hide any div or text when ion-menu is opened in Ionic 5 using Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I want to hide the toolbar `.custom-nav-link` div when the ionic side menu will open and again show this when the side menu is closed.
How to detect and apply conditions in HTML based on ion-menu is open or close?

[image]

```
<ion-toolbar>
  <div class="containers">
    <div class="logo" >
      <h4>My Toolbar</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="custom-nav-link" slot="end">
      <nav class="desktop-nav">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li *ngFor="let p of buttonLinks">
            <a href="">{{p.title}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="">
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-menu-button menu="userMenu">
          <ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>
        </ion-menu-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </div>

  </div>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

public isMenuOpen: boolean = false;

constructor(public menuCtrl:MenuController){}

ngOnInit() {   // or on click of menu button
    this.menuCtrl.isOpen('userMenu').then(res => {
        this.isMenuOpen = res;
    })
}
```

and html

```
<div *ngIf="!isMenuOpen" class="custom-nav-link" slot="end">
  <nav class="desktop-nav">
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li *ngFor="let p of buttonLinks">
        <a href="">{{p.title}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="">
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-menu-button menu="userMenu">
      <ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>
    </ion-menu-button>
  </ion-buttons>
</div>
```

Comment: this solution does not listen to changes as it sets the value once

Answer (score 0):

You can to Use MenuController For that

```
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(public menuCtrl:MenuController){}
```

In HTML

```
<ion-toolbar>
  <div class="containers">
    <div class="logo" >
      <h4>My Toolbar</h4>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="!menuCtrl.isOpen('menuId')" class="custom-nav-link" slot="end">
      <nav class="desktop-nav">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li *ngFor="let p of buttonLinks">
            <a href="">{{p.title}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="">
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-menu-button menu="userMenu">
          <ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>
        </ion-menu-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </div>

  </div>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Comment: I used this but not working, only the browser is loading for an infinite time. Is there any other way?

Comment: can you share that in stackblitz for reference

Comment: @Md.IkbalHossen for me, the reason for the infinite load time was because MenuController's isOpen function returns a promise and not a boolean.

Comment: this solution causes the browser to hang/freeze

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the component looks for the state of the menu every second (interval) and sets it on a property that can be accessed from the template

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public menuEnabled: boolean
  public menuIsopen: boolean

  constructor(public menuController: MenuController) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.menuEnabled = false
    this.menuIsOpen = false
    setInterval(async () => {
      this.menuEnabled = await this.menuController.isEnabled()
      this.menuIsOpen = await this.menuController.isOpen()
    }, 1000)
  }

  // you can also try using an observable
  // menuEnabled() {
  //   return from(this.menuController.isEnabled())
  // }

}
```

Then in your template

```
<div *ngIf="!menuEnabled || !menuIsOpen"></div>
```